# Can't bind string params to mysqli prepared statement (php)

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm having trouble binding string parameters to a statement. I'm using this example code: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php#106402

Now I'm trying to bind parameters to a statement using that function.

Binding an integer works fine:

```
iQuery("SELECT * FROM sometable WHERE somecol=?", array('i', 123));
```

Strings like this also work:

```
iQuery("SELECT * FROM sometable WHERE someothercol=?", array('s', 'foo'));
```

This, however doesn't work:

```
$value = 'foo';
iQuery("SELECT * FROM sometable WHERE someothercol=?", array('s', $value));
// Error message:  Parameter 3 to mysqli_stmt::bind_param() expected to be a reference, value given
// (Occurs at the $method->invokeArgs line)
```

When I put quotes around `$val` it doesn't give the error, but no rows are returned.

Does anyone know what causes this and how I can solve my problem?

---

**UPDATE/SOLUTION:**

Ok, got it! I should have read both that message and the sample better. 
Solution was to add & before the variable.

```
$value = 'foo';
iQuery("...", array('s'), &$value);
```

Comment: Because, you're using the wrong variable. `$val != $value;`

Comment: Sorry, my bad when posting. edited.

Comment: You'll have to show what your `iquery` function is doing. Probably you're copying around that array or its values somewhere. this would probably work fine if you were directly calling mysqli_stmt_bind_param

Comment: @MarcB Check the link for the implementation of the iQuery function. Haven't changed it.

Comment: If you were following the sample exactly, you'd have `$value = array('s', 'foo')`. Since you're passing the argument in directly inside the function calls, it can't be bound. the array will cease to exist when iquery() returns and the array cleaned up and the binding destroyed. assigning the array to a var outside of the function makes it persist

Comment: @MarcB Editing that doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

<s>Well, since you're using different variable names, no wonder:</s>

```
$value = 'foo';
^^^^^^---full name

iQuery("..snip...", array('s', $val));
                                ^^^^---undefined var here
```

Comment: *"The plot thickens"* - OP changed the question/code.

Comment: Sorry, that was my bad when posting it here. Not the issue in my real code. Edited the question